sqlalchemy: how to define a Column with two possible names?
I have to define a column test_a but test_a sometimes has a name test_a but sometimes test_b. I
Could you give me an advice what I can improve / what should I check or do ?
I expect that if test_a will come then test_a = test_a but when test_b will come then test_a = test_b.
I was trying to do something like this: test_a = Column('test_a', Float, key='test_b') but it does not work when test_b appears.

What is the use-case here?  Are you doing something like foo = Foo(**kwargs) and the keys in kwargs are variable and coming directly from an external source, like an API call?

See the linked question regarding "generated columns". You can make test_b a generated column that's simply equal to test_a.
